# Free FTP Client that automatically opens files for editing?

Tags: untagged

My company currently uses FTP Voyager as the main way for remote employees to access and edit their project files.  We have a multi-user license for the non-secure version – i.e. usernames/passwords are sent in cleartext.   There is a financial cost to upgrading to the secure version that can do SSL or TLS authorization.

I would like to go to a free secure FTP client but FTP Voyager has one feature that I have not seen in any other.  It allows you to click on a file in its Remote folder and it will then automatically download it and open it using the correct program for editing. i.e. .xls files open in Excel, .dwg files open in AutoCad, etc. Once you have finished editing the file and close it, you are prompted  to do an upload. And it can do this for multiple open files.  Without this feature there is a high chance that people will download a file, edit it and then forget to upload it – or they upload the old version.

Does anyone know of a free FTP client that can do the same the job, and has support for secure authentication?

Answer (score 2):

[The FileZilla client](http://filezilla-project.org/)

- Supports SSH or FTP over TLS.
- You can use the "View/Edit" option to edit individual files in their default application (taken from the system defaults).

Once you make a change to the file and switch back to FileZilla it will prompt you to upload you changes, you can do this as many times as you like, if you are finished editing there is a check box to allow you to delete the tempory file.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the FileZilla has this function. As with WinSCP I'm evaluating it to see if people are going to be ok switching from FTP Voyager.

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP has that function

Comment: +1; WinSCP comes a very close second for quick edits.

Comment: Thank you, I've just downloaded WinSCP and I'm trying it out.  At the moment, FTP Voyager seems to have a better interface but this may be just what I'm used to.

Answer (score 0):

Another one very nice FTP client is [WinSPC](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) ,
Maybe it will fit your needs,

Another one solution is to build your own FTP client according to your requests,
I do not think that will rocket science with todays goodies of .NET controls.